# want to implement php if else for substituting value

Tags: php, curl

I execute `foreach` loop and the output is `$a= 0,1,42`.  I want to implement `if else` condition in the output. I want if output `is 0 then`.
I want to set it CJ and if output is 1 then it is set to 01 else print same value as return from loop.

```
foreach($arrel as $val)
 {
    echo $a = $val[0];
 }
```

Comment: You need to be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
foreach($arrel as $val) {
 switch ($val[0]){
  case 0:
   echo $a = "CJ";
   break;
  case 1:
   echo $a = "01";
   break;
  default:
   //Default response.
   echo $a = $val[0];
   break;
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
foreach($arrel as $val)
{
    if($val == 0){
        echo $a = "CJ";
    }else if($val == 1){ 
        echo $a = "01";
    }else{
        echo $a = $val;
    }
}
```